# Issue when showing Snackbar in androidx

Tags: android, androidx, android-snackbar

I have recently switched to android and I am having some issues when trying to display a snackbar.

I build my snackbar like this:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, Strings.empty(), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
```

Snackbar belongs to this class 
`com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar`

I have added this as a dependency

`com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06`

For my activity I have used `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` AND `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge` but I got the same issue no matter which theme I have used.

And now the error I get is this:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x101009b a=1}
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:528)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:783)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:704)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:700)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
at com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:188)

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
```

Any ideas why this crashes?

Thanks

Comment: First step try the latest 1.1.0. Currently 1.1.0-beta02.

Comment: Can you put the entire class here to view whats wrong

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I tried and I get the same error

Comment: Post your theme. You have to use a MaterialComponents theme or a Material Components Bridge in any case.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I use parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge"

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti any idea?

Comment: I should try to replicate the issue. It seems that the problem is with some color not defined.

Comment: Did you check your xml?

Comment: What is Strings.empty()?

Comment: @ArnoldBrown empty string ""

Comment: I am not able to replicate the error with an empty project using the theme `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge` and `1.1.0-beta02` and `1.2.0-alpha02`.

Comment: Can you post the xml?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti could the issue not be with the theme? should I look for something else?

Comment: @ArnoldBrown You were right, the issue was within my custom layout, it failed when trying to inflate a Button. Thanks.

Comment: @Adrian so it is closed?